# How to change the value of a string every second with jquery

Tags: jquery

i have been trying to change the value of a string every seconds with jquery and haven't been able to achieve it. here is my code:

```
var bee = {
a: 0,
b: 1,
c:2
 };
```

i want to able to change the values of 'a' 'b' 'c' every second for example:

- i want "a" to count from 0-9 and return to 0
- i want "b" to count from 1-9 and return to 1
- i want "c" to count from 2-9 and return to 2.

i want it to keep repeating this process every second.
how do i achieve this?

Comment: jQuery is not what you are looking for here. Ask Google about `setInterval` and `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your result by using setInterval.

Take a look at the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nmL9u3wu/

```js
var a = 0,
    b = 1,
    c = 2;

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        a = (a + 1) > 9 ? 0 : (a + 1);
        b = (b + 1) > 9 ? 1 : (b + 1);
        c = (c + 1) > 9 ? 2 : (c + 1);
        $("#a").text(a);
        $("#b").text(b);
        $("#c").text(c);
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    a: <span id='a'>0</span>
    b: <span id='b'>1</span>
    c: <span id='c'>2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer!  Can you explain the purpose of the ":" on your codes? I'm learning jQuery and I found this interesting. Thanks!

Comment: ternary operator. please check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Thank you! I'll make sure to check it! :)